# I cannot install python threading library on my Windows 7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have successfully installed pip on my computer and other libraries using "pip install 'library name'" command. I got all the libraries needed for my project except for "threading"!I could not find anything online about it and asked others and no one could help. Any help is appreciate it. I have Python 2.7.9 version.

Here is the error I am getting

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The error is complaining that it can't find this lib, which makes sense. Because this `threading` is already in python's standard library, You don't need to manually install it.

Just try:

```
import threading
```

It should work fine.

Comment: You mean writing it inside my program? If so, I already have it. Now when I run the program, I get this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002620/error-while-running-python-program-with-requests-and-threading-lib

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with `threading`. In fact, you can see there was `C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py` in the error log.  It's already there. You don't have to install it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! It was a problem with the camera WiFi connection and you were right, the lib was installed

Comment: You can write it from the command line. Try this:  python -c 'import threading'   If that doesn't give you an error, then you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

just type 
pip install thread

Note thread cant be install in versions less than 3.0