# Error while running python program with requests and threading lib

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests

I am new to python. I was having trouble installing threading library because I had an error. I asked and was told that the library already existed and therefore I was getting this error. Now, when I run my program I get this error. I am not sure how to fix it or what to do. The other problem is that this problem makes the terminal not responsive (cannot enter anything or exit). I should mention that others are running the same program without problems (they know python). The code is for Sony QX100 camera.

```
Line 24: s = start_liveview()

Line 45: response = requests.post(cam_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

Line 109: response = sony_api_call("startLiveview", [])
```

Note: no semi colon are used at the end of the lines (not sure if that is relevant).
[current error and problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUMXX.jpg)...
[error installing threading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcm84.jpg)...

Comment: You should edit your question to include the information in those images. If you click on the DOS window icon, you can use the items in the Edit menu to copy the text out of the window.

Comment: What's your code like?

Comment: It is fo Sony QX100 camera. Line 24: s = start_liveview() ... Line 109:     response = sony_api_call("startLiveview", []) ...
Line 45:     response = requests.post(cam_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

Comment: Please put the code in the question and format it so it looks well.

Comment: @Helena we need more information about the code than what you provide. I'm a requests core-developer and my email is publicly accessible. If you need to share the code privately, you can email it to me. That said, you should really use this forum if you're able to post the code publicly

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. It wasn't anything wrong with the code. The camera WiFi connection had problem connecting to the PC.